# Use Excel to open a search window in Window Explorer

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, windows-explorer

I have seen some topics on the subject, but I haven't been able to find exactly what I need. And because I am not familiar with VBA I have not been able to tweak the code to get it to work.

**Here's what I am looking to accomplish:**

I would like to have a macro (or excel formula) that when I click on the hyperlink it will open a Windows File Explorer in search mode.

In cell A1 is my path name (C:/users/images)

In cell A2 is the file name (Butterfly)

In cell A3 is the hyperlink that when I click on it it will open windows file explorer searching in the path C:/users/images for any files containing butterfly

**Here is what I have found so far**

```
Sub SearchFolder()

Call Shell("explorer.exe " & Chr(34) & "search-ms:query=butterfly&crumb=location:C:\users\images" & Chr(34), vbNormalFocus)

End Sub
```

This bit of code works, but it is hard coded. I need to made it dynamic so that the marco can pick up the the path and file name from the excel cells.

Any help is great! And like I said I am not familiar with VBA (it took me 3 days to find that code) so if you can provide the code as will that would be great!

Comment: `Call Shell("explorer.exe " & Chr(34) & "search-ms:query=" & ws.Range("A2").Value2 & "&crumb=location:" & ws.Range("A1").Value2 & Chr(34), vbNormalFocus)` Where `ws` is the relevant worksheet.

Comment: @PEH Thank you for the help I was able to get the search window to pop up.

Comment: My other requirement. I will have many different path names in Column A and many different file names in Column B. I wanted to create a hyperlink in Column C so when I clicked on it would search for the path and file from Column A and B. How would I go about doing that? (I realize I didn't explain that properly in my original question).

The Excel sheet would look something like this: 

`A          |  B      |  C`


`\path\   | worm | _Link_`


`\path2\ | fly      | _Link_`